ANdroid Gradle Invalid character escape '\U'
When introducing the following line in gradle I get the below error:
arguments += "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${projectDir}\\..\\..\\vcpkg\\scripts\\buildsystems\\vcpkg.cmake"

What could be the problem?
    CMake Error at C:/Users/ionut/project/android/app/.cxx/Debug/1uj4j5n5/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.27.3/CMakeSystem.cmake:13 (set):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/Users/ionut/project/android/app/.cxx/Debug/1uj4j5n5/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.27.3/CMakeSystem.cmake:13

  when parsing string

    C:\Users\ionut\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125

  Invalid character escape '\U'.

The content of the line 13:
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK "C:\Users\ionut\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125")


What is in line 13 in C:/Users/ionut/project/android/app/.cxx/Debug/1uj4j5n5/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.27.3/CMakeSystem.cmake? Please copy that line into your question.

@Robert I added the line into the quesiton

@Computable Using forward slash results into the same issue.

You should change line 13 as follows
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK "C\:\\Users\\ionut\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\26.1.10909125")

This is because you are using Cmake on Windows.
For some reason when setting env variables on Windows
it won't accept the forward slash path style.

Are you sure the backslash before the colon is really necessary? I think it should be C:\\  and not C\:\\  Also it would be good if you describe why this is necessary the way you posted in your answer.

@Robert for me when I try to write without escaping the ":" I get the following error:
Windows file separators () and drive letter separators (':') must be escaped (\) in property files
